# Laravel Validation Rule Asterisk

Tags: php, laravel

Basically i want to do validation like this in laravel 10

```
$request->validate([
    'parent_id' => ['nullable', 'exists:categories'],
    'translations.*.name' => ['required', 'string'],
    'translations.*.description' => ['nullable', 'string'],
    'translations.*.meta.*' => ['nullable', 'string'],
    'media.image.*' => ['nullable', 'string'],
    'status' => ['required', 'integer'],
]);
```

And my input section looks like this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="translations[{{ $locale }}][name]" value="{{ old('translations.' . $locale . '.name') }}">
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="translations[{{ $locale }}][description]">{{ old('translations.' . $locale . '.description') }}</textarea>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="translations[{{ $locale }}][meta][title]" value="{{ old('translations.' . $locale . 'meta.title') }}">
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="translations[{{ $locale }}][meta][description]">{{ old('translations.' . $locale . 'meta.description') }}</textarea>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="translations[{{ $locale }}][meta][keywords]" value="{{ old('translations.' . $locale . 'meta.keywords') }}">
```

I didn't fill in form input name but no `$errors`, when i delete all form input meta, validation work fine

This is what $_POST look like

```
"translations" => array:2 [▼
    "en" => array:3 [▼
      "name" => ""
      "description" => ""
      "meta" => array:3 [▼
        "title" => ""
        "description" => ""
        "keywords" => ""
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

I don't know why `$errors` not showing or `->validate()` not working, `'translations.*.meta.*' => ['nullable', 'string']` or `form input meta`?

Comment: You don't get errors because you are defining a validation rule `nullable` to your meta fields which exactly match your `POST` request data and an empty value cannot be `filled` on the form input field again because they are `empty` by default.